# How do I programmatically open an external URL on a button click with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-jetpack-compose

How do I programmatically open an external URL on a button click with Jetpack Compose?

```
@Composable
fun MyButton() {
  Button(onClick = {
    //enter code here
  })
}
```

Answer (score 113):

An easier alternative is to use `LocalUriHandler`:

```
val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current
uriHandler.openUri(uri)
```

Keep it short and sweet

Comment: Note that this doesn't work inside the `onClick` handler. I get an error: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function" when accessing `LocalUriHandler` inside the `onClick` handler.
`

Comment: @Kukiwon You need to hoist `val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current` outside the `onClick` handler. Then you should be able to call `uriHandler.openUri(uri)` from within your handler

Answer (score 24):

Here is a possible way to do it:

```
@Composable
fun MyButton() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val intent = remember { Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/")) }

    Button(onClick = { context.startActivity(intent) }) {
        Text(text = "Navigate to Google!")
    }
}
```

Inside @Composable functions, you have one thing called ["Composition Locals"](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop#composition-locals).

> CompositionLocal classes allow passing data implicitly through composable functions to its composable descendants

LocalContext is one of these classes.
The Intent specified, is the common way to open an external URL on Android.

Answer (score 10):

I found that accessing `LocalUriHandler.current` inside the `onClick` handler would raise an error: `"@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"`

I solved it by moving this line of code *outside* the Button:

```kotlin
val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current
Button(onClick = {
    uriHandler.openUri(...)
) {
    // Your label goes here
}
```

Comment: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW)

Comment: @TheMJ that happens because the implementation of `uriHandler.openUri()` calls `context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)))` and it doesn't handle the scenario when no Activity is found (the method `startActivity()` throws the exception `ActivityNotFoundException`).

Answer (score 0):

@Composable
fun WebButton() {

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val webIntent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"))

OutlinedButton(onClick = { context.startActivity(webIntent) }, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
    Text( text = "OPEN WEB",
        )
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I've been using **CustomTabsIntent** which is another possibility when it comes to open a link in the phone browser.

```
// Within your @Composable function define the context val
val context = LocalContext.current

//Then in your modifier clickable use the CustomTabsIntent builder
modifier = Modifier
           .padding(start = 24.dp, end = 16.dp)
           .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
           .clickable { 
              CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build().launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(pageUrl))
           }
```